# Rendering error when publishing Page, which doesn't occur on preview

Tags: publishing, web8.5

I am getting an error while publishing a Page in SDL Web 8.5.

Error :[image]

When the Page is previewed, it works fine.

The event viewer log :

```
    JScriptException: Expression 'RenderComponentPresentation()' had error 'String cannot be of zero length.
    Parameter name: oldValue'
    String cannot be of zero length.
    Parameter name: oldValue
    String cannot be of zero length.
    Parameter name: oldValue


    Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing
    Errorcode: 2049
    User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

    StackTrace Information Details:
       at Microsoft.JScript.LateBinding.Call(Object[] arguments, Boolean construct, Boolean brackets, VsaEngine engine)
       at Microsoft.JScript.Call.Evaluate()
    eval code: Line 1 - Error: String cannot be of zero length.
    Parameter name: oldValue

       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Expression.JScriptEvaluator.EvaluateToObject(String statement)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Expression.JScriptEvaluator.EvaluateToString(String statement)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Package.EvaluateExpression(String expression)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.TransformValueReferences(Package package, StringReference templateReference, Regex startTagExpression, String endTag)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.TransformRegions(Package package, String dreamweaverTemplate)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.TransformOptionalRegions(Package package, StringReference templateReference)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.TransformRegions(Package package, String dreamweaverTemplate)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.TransformRepeatingRegions(Package package, StringReference templateReference)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.TransformRegions(Package package, String dreamweaverTemplate)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template template, Package package)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template template, IdentifiableObject itemToRender)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TemplatingRenderer.Render(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, RenderedItem renderedItem, RenderContext renderContext)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, RenderContext context)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.RenderAndPackage(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, List`1 processedItems, PublishTransaction publishTransaction, TransportPackage transportPackage)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.HandlePublishRequest(PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.ProcessPublishTransaction(PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.QueueMessageHandler.HandleMessage()
```

*Note: I have migrated the contents from Tridion 2011 to web 8.5.  In 2011 the publshing works fine.*

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to "debug" the Template in the Template Builder, is it failing on a DWT Template Building Block, if so can you perhaps **edit** your question and update it with the source of that DWT TBB?

Comment: Yes. I tried that one also . It is working fine in Template Builder.

Comment: You can try debugging the publisher service: attach your Visual Studio debugger to TcmPublisher.exe and let it break on any exception. Then check the call stack to find the value for the expression/statement parameter.

Comment: Thanks Rick. It was the TBB that was expecting a Publication Target name as Staging and Live where as I have created a new one as "Staging New". That's where the rendering was getting failed. Now it works fine with the old ones.